# What are async Functions in JavaScript or Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

what is the difference if a normal method or async method is called on an object ?

```
(1) myObject.handleUpdate()   // conventional method
(2) myObject.handleUpdate()   // handleUpdate is declared async
```

I know that async methods return always promise. But apart from that. Does async method run in a separate thread ? And what does it mean if an async method is called in a test framework. You need to wait for it ? In contrast a normal method (1) is called in the same thread you can call it without any hooks in a test framework

Comment: You should name the async variant of handleUpdate() to handleUpdateAsync() so that you know the function is awaitable.

Comment: Since this is tagged [tag:jestjs], are you familiar with https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous? No, it means nothing special, an `async function` is treated the same by the test runner as any other promise-returning function.

Answer (score 0):

If you worked with promises, you know that async calculations are synced up again by placing the subsequent one inside the callback of the `.then(…)` method of the Promise instance of the original one.

The `await` keyword is a syntax sugar that does exactly that under the hood, — just a nicer syntax for something that would otherwise require a chain of `.then(…)` calls.

The `async` keyword allows using the `await` keyword immediately inside of the async function body.

There really isn't much more of a difference. For example, there is no way of providing the callback for `.catch(…)`, you have to wrap the calculation in `try..catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that async methods return always promise. But apart from that.

That's basically it. It always returns a promise, and allows use of the `await` keyword inside the function. A return statement in the async function will cause the promise to resolve with that value. A throw statement in the async function will cause the promise to reject.

> Does async method run in a separate thread ?

No.

> And what does it mean if an async method is called in a test framework. You need to wait for it ?

Yes, probably. In most cases, your test will care about when the promise resolves. To find out when that happens, you will need to `await` the promise (or call `.then` on it). If for some reason you don't care about when the promise resolves then you don't need to await it, but that's less common.

Comment: so why should I wait for the promise if the method just finishes sequentially ? It does not run in a separate thread and just blocks like a normal method call. That's what you were saying ?

Comment: I thought whenever a method returns a Promise it is async which means if you don't use await it will be run in a different thread, non blocking.

Comment: A promise is an object that represents an eventual value. It's up to you to decide what code calculates that value. The fact you're using a promise to represent the result doesn't dictate whether you use a separate thread to do the calculation. 99% of the time, you'll be writing code that does not use a thread, such as `fetch` to get data from a server, or `setTimeout` to wait a bit. These examples are nonblocking, but they don't do this by using a separate javascript thread, they do it using the normal event loop on the main thread.

Comment: `so why should I wait for the promise if the method just finishes sequentially ? It does not run in a separate thread and just blocks like a normal method call. That's what you were saying ?` It only blocks if you tell it to block. But i'm assuming you wrote code that does something asynchronous and then resumes, such as a `fetch` or `setTimeout` wrapped in `new Promise`. If you want to know when this is done, you must await. The async function runs until it hits an await, then returns a promise. The rest of the function will run later and determine what value the promise resolves to.

Comment: Sorry my confusion comes from the fact that you can define a function with keyword async which has no await inside. And this function behaves just like a normal function. So in my opinion the compiler should output a warning or error for this , because the async is redundant

Comment: Yeah, async without await doesn't make much sense. There are lint rules that can warn you if you do so: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/require-await or https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/require-await/

Comment: ok. If you do await fetch(..) this thread will block until the response comes back . 
And even the fetch call will be handled in this thread . That's my understanding

Comment: It's all in one thread, but the thread does not block. If the thread blocked, your browser would freeze up. When you call `fetch`, the browser does just as much as it needs to do to send off the request, then returns a promise to you. You `await` this promise, which causes your function to return a promise to its parent. Since you've returned, other code can now run. Some time later, the fetch finishes and the original promise resolves. A task gets queued in the event loop. Assuming no other code is running, the task gets picked up and the code on the left side of the `await` executes.